# How to undo a drawing? Making a stopwatch and the text overlaps as it updates

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval, stopwatch

i'm making a stopwatch that is working, but when it changes, the text overlaps itself because it is drawing the text repeatedly. If i remove the strokeText and fillText from the interval, then it does not change. It stays the same. How can i make the function undo itself, or delete the text at the beginning of the interval?

```
function drawTimer() {
    var fontSize = 15;
    graph.lineWidth = playerConfig.textBorderSize;
    graph.fillStyle = playerConfig.textColor;
    graph.strokeStyle = playerConfig.textBorder;
    graph.miterLimit = 1;
    graph.lineJoin = 'round';
    graph.textAlign = 'right';
    graph.textBaseline = 'middle';
    graph.font = 'bold ' + fontSize + 'px sans-serif';

    var gameTimeMinutes = 0;
    var gameTimeSeconds = 1;
    var gameTime = "";

    function addTime() {
        gameTimeSeconds += 1;

        if (gameTimeSeconds < 10) {
            gameTime = gameTimeMinutes + " : 0" + gameTimeSeconds;
        } else {
            gameTime = gameTimeMinutes + " : " + gameTimeSeconds;
        }

        if (gameTimeSeconds == 60) {
            gameTimeSeconds = 0;
            gameTimeMinutes++;
        }

        graph.strokeText(gameTime, 50, 50);
        graph.fillText(gameTime, 50, 50);
    }

setInterval(addTime, 1000);
}
```

Code explanation: gameTimeSeconds is the seconds on the right of the colon, minutes is on the left, and its saying if the seconds is not double digits, then show the zero on the left of it. It also says to add one to minutes when seconds reach 60. Then, write the time. Ex: 0:01, 0:20, 1:20, etc. . Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you just need to clear your canvas on each interval: `context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);`

Comment: This stopwatch is placed on a game, so clearing the canvas will destroy the game.

Comment: Then you'll probably need to draw it on a separate canvas.

Answer (score 0):

You need to draw each 'layer' every frame for anything that might overlap.
For example, draw the back of the stopwatch, then the texton each frame.

I.E. whatever is drawing the text and background needs to happen inside of addTime